# before_create throwing NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**schema:**

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "total_stars"
    t.integer  "average_stars"
  end

  create_table "stars", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "starable_id"
    t.string   "starable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "number"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "stars", ["starable_id", "starable_type"], name: "index_stars_on_starable_id_and_starable_type"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**models:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stars, :as => :starable, :dependent => :destroy 
  belongs_to :user
end

class Star < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :add_to_total_stars

  belongs_to :starable, :polymorphic => true

  protected

  def add_to_total_stars
    if [Post].include?(starable.class)
      self.starable.update_column(:total_stars, starable.total_stars + self.number)
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

So I tried creating a star in the Rails console like this:

```
post = Post.first
user = User.first
star = post.stars.build(number: 1)
star.user_id = user.id
```

And everything goes OK 'till here. But when I try to save it:

```
star.save
```

I get this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass    from
>   /home/alex/rails/rating/app/models/star.rb:10:in`add_to_total_stars' 
>   from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__956917800__create__callbacks'    from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`
>   run_callbacks'  from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:303:in `create_record'   from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in`create_record'    from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:466:in `create_or_update'  from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in`block in create_or_update'   from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in `_run__956917800__save__callbacks'  from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`
>   run_callbacks'

What could be the cause?

(I'm using Rails 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the value of `Post.first.total_stars` is nil. Going by your schema and model examples you allow null in the database and do not validate it's presence in ActiveRecord.

If it makes sense to default this value to 0, then you should set the default value in the schema.

So I would add the following to your schema:

```
create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
  # ...
  t.integer  "total_stars", null: false, default: 0
end
```

And the following validation in your model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stars, :as => :starable, :dependent => :destroy 
  belongs_to :user

  validates :total_stars, presence: true
end
```

As an aside, I would get rid of `total_stars` altogether and let rails do this for you with the `counter_cache` option instead. Here's the [Railscast screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that error because `starable.total_stars` is nil in your callback method. you need to ensure that `starable.total_stars` is set to 0 ro you can call to_i method on it (`nil.to_i #=> 0`) to ensure that you have 0 if it is not initialized